# What is the g++ flag -DIL_STD used for?

Tags: g++

I see the following in lots of makefiles on my system, but I can't for the life of me find it in the g++ manual:

```
-DIL_STD
```

What does this flag do?

Comment: You need to actually read the manual. A string search won't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-D` option is [documented here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

It defines the macro `IL_STD` as `1`, equivalent to having

```
#define IL_STD 1
```

at the top of your source file.

What your source does with it is another matter, but a quick search turns up [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399983); apparently it's used to enable some STL features, but I wouldn't expect it to be necessary in anything modern. But it's quite possible that `IL_STD` is used for something else. You might want to search your source file, and anything it `#include`s, for that identifier to see what it actually means.